# Force download of multiple files with header() in php

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to download multiple files using `header()` in a `while` loop, but only one file gets downloaded. Why?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $row['name'] . '.vcf');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only transfer one file from server side at a time.  Typical workarounds are:

1. tar/zip them up into one file on server side.
2. use javascript to window.open multiple files for download.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The HTTP protocol does not have support for downloading multiple files. The most common workaround is to put the files in a zip archive for the client to download.

Comment: Actually, Chrome supports this.

Comment: @Dereckson Then please add an answer to this question! That is quite interesting news!

Answer (score 1):

headers ca be set only once before outputting any data.

As you loop you set some headers after that you must output something. In the next loop you will not set any headers.

Please read [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)